# alc282 on laptop sounding noticeably superior to alc1220 on atx mobo. How can I fix this?

Tags: audio, drivers, motherboard

I'm operating under the assumption that alc282 < alc1220.

I have an old laptop that uses alc282 realtek. I recently built a computer with a mobo that supports alc1220. I'm very confused why the alc282, the laptop, sounds much better than the alc1220 of the new rig. Assuming this is not supposed to be the case, what can I do to try and get the alc1220 sounding better? THe board is: https://www.gigabyte.com/ca/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver-chipset ryzen on windows 10.

The laptop by comparison used intel and windows 8.1

I tested the quality with 3 different sets of speakers. On all of them the alc1220 sounded much worse, as if the sounds were being played through smaller sets of speakers. I'd rank it as anywhere from 15-25% less richness/signal depending on the song (drowned out sounding). I didn't notice any improvement as I updated the audio drivers via the website above.

Comment: In this situation I think I'd buy a cheap usb sound card and try on both computers to rule out audio settings and operating system differences between the two pc, and then if the w10 sounded ok return the usb card for a credit against a pci one (or keep the usb) and ditch the on board one. While frustrating that the built in one seems not up to spec, how much time is worth wasting if a good quality replacement audio card can be had for under 20 dollars?

Comment: As an aside, the set of hp mini 800 g3 that my office purchased all sounded absolutely awful, telephone audio quality. A driver update sounded massively better though I note you did say you'd tried this.. have you tried older drivers?

Comment: They only had 3 drivers available on the website to choose from for windows 64bit. Realtek Audio Driver (Note) Win10 ver.1903 supported. [6.0.8688.1]. Realtek Audio Driver (Note) Win10 ver.1809 supported. [6.0.1.8597]. Realtek HD Audio Driver. I downloaded and installed them all in order of oldest to newest. Noticed no difference. I didn't uninstall anything separately before installing via the exe's. I couldn't tell in device manager what drivers were which since the names are all slightly different and there's like 3 sets of names or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be fixed software wise anyways.